# in sql between @startdate and @enddate does not compare time part ? How to compare time parts of date

Tags: t-sql

I have query like this

```
SELECT AVAILABILITY_DATE_TIME FROM APPT_PROVIDER_AVAILABILITY
            WHERE AVAILABILITY_DATE_TIME between @START_DATE  AND @END_DATE
```

suppose i have 
if @startdate = '2/11/2010 **11:31**:00 AM' and @enddate = '2/11/2010 **11:56**:00 AM'

then difference is zero its ignoring time part  .

If you can provide query plz use

table name : APPT_PROVIDER_AVAILABILITY
, column name : AVAILABILITY_DATE_TIME

and @start_date and @enddate as params

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean? 'BETWEEN' takes into account the time portion of datetimes?

Comment: I can no longer edit my first comment above (the question mark at end might be construed as ambiguous), but to be absolutely clear: the time portion is NOT being ignored.

Comment: i mean between DOES NOT take into account time part , how to get aroung this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does **not** ignore the time portion.

- Check your data- that you really do have a record in that range
- Check your culture settings- that it's not treating the string '2/11/2010' as '11/2/2010' when converting it to a datetime
- Change your parameter assignment.  Even if your culture setting is right you should still use an unambiguous value for the assignment.  Something more like this: `2010-02-11 11:31:00 AM`
- Check your parameter definitions, that you're not using the newer 'date' type.
- If all else fails, write it out in long hand: `WHERE ([column] >= @startdate AND [column] <= @enddate)`